# Odoo 12 : Not enought limit time to finish the backup?

Tags: odoo-12

I use the auto_backup to backup production database everyday.
It was working well until now.
Now, the backup can't finish until the end, I mean, I get the half size of the .zip file and it is impossible to restore it.
Normaly, the backup takes about 15mn.
I think that it's related to the Odoo configuration.
Here it is :

```
workers = 3
longpolling_port = 8072
limit_memory_soft = 2013265920
limit_memory_hard = 2415919104
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 600
limit_time_real = 3600
limit_time_real_cron = 3600
proxy_mode = True
```

Can you help me?
I have another question, What does mean limit_time_real_cron = -1 if the limit_time_real_cron = 0 is unlimited?

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase `limit_time_cpu`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it